# VSCode Associating a file without extension to xml

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to associate all files without extension to xml format in VSCode.

When I do below, it makes all files (even with extensions) as xml. 
"files.associations": {
        "*": "xml"
    }

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: `{ "*.": "xml" }`?

Comment: This wont work.   its like having a regex for file name without extension

Comment: No, it's a wildcard expression, which is what it looks like `files.associations` uses. The example in the documentation/comment uses wildcards: "Configure file associations to languages (e.g. `"*.extension": "html"`)."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **This solution does not work for the latest versions.**

```json
"files.associations": {
    "[!.]*": "xml",
},
```

---

### For the latest versions, you need to add a rule for each file length.

> The example shows a solution for files up to 30 characters long.

Far from the best solution, but no better solution has yet been found.

```json
"files.associations": {
    "[!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
    "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "xml",
}
```

Comment: This worked for me for c++ Linux include files, e.g. when opening `<string>`; though, note that it only worked when I did `"cpp"`, the exact right Language Mode string, rather than `"c++"`, which did not work. Thanks.

Comment: Update: Actually, this seems to be causing **all** files to open in whatever Language Mode... :/

Comment: from your comments, I did not understand what needs to be done or what is not working as it should

Comment: This answer's approach will cause literally all files that are opened to open in the specified Language Mode that was specified, i.e. `"xml"` or `"cpp"`, whatever was specified here.

Comment: all files without extension (no dot in full name) will open as 'xml' files.

Comment: Along with all other files. I'm telling you what happens.

Comment: I have no problems. Can you give an example of such a file that opens with the wrong extension and vscode settings?

Comment: No because I'm not a 4 year old.

Comment: I don't care about age. Everything works for me as it should. I can't reproduce your problem. Check it on vscode without settings.

Comment: This does not work for me either.  Any file is opened as the association.  In fact it changes the settings.json association when I save the setting.